# Adb push shared_prefs file permissions in Android 11

Tags: android, adb

Until Android 11 I could easily push an xml file to `./storage` or `./sdcard` and then copy it under `/data/user_de/0/com.myapp/shared_prefs` to prepare the app for testing.

However, with the new storage updates in Android 11, it seems this is not possible anymore. I even grant `READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` permissions to the app:

```
adb shell appops set --uid com.myapp READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE allow
adb shell appops set --uid com.myapp WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE allow
adb shell appops set --uid com.myapp MANAGE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE allow
```

but still I get `Permission denied` on a dir that is part of the shared storage:

```
adb shell run-as com.myapp ls -alR /sdcard/Android/media
ls: /sdcard/Android/media: Permission denied
```

According to [this](https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/manage-all-files) it should work but it doesn't.

Also tried the `appops` to allow for legacy storage with no luck:

```
adb shell cmd appops set com.myapp android:legacy_storage allow
adb shell am force-stop com.myapp
```

Any ideas on how to copy a file from pc/mac to device in a shared_prefs dir?

Comment: One can not create .xml files in public Music or Pictures directory on an Android 11 device. Use public Documents or Download directory instead.

Comment: Tried that...still doesn't work ```adb shell run-as com.myapp ls /sdcard/Download
ls: /sdcard/Download: Permission denied```. Tried with Documents, /sdcard/Android/media.

Answer (score 0):

you can push `shared_prefs` while using `run-as` command, just make sure you copied the file `/sdcard/Android/data/com.Yourapp` and then it works like a charm!